# How can I loop over elements of variable length rank 1 tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a way to get a variable dimension of placeholder tensor to loop over it? Example:

```
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[None])

def loop_cond(t, k):
    N = t.get_shape()[0].value
    tf.less(k, N-1)
```

I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'`.

How can I loop over elements of variable length rank 1 tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) to get rid of known shape requirement at graph construction time. Following code would solve the issue.

```
def loop_cond(t, k):
    N = tf.stack([tf.shape(t)[0]])
    tf.less(k, N-1)
```

Comment: I get `ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'sim_loop/LoopCond' (op: 'LoopCond') with input shapes: [1].`

Comment: I reshaped before return as follows: `N = tf.reshape(N, ())` and it works.